# Wrong image src url when using Python scrapy

Tags: python, image, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape image from en eCommerce website using scrapy, but for some of the items(5-10 out of 180) image src output is similar to this -

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8A .
```

For the rest of the items I get the correct image URL.
Can someone help me with this.

My code is for image src extraction is

```
 image = response.css('.productimage img::attr(src)').extract()
```

And due to this I am getting an error while downloading the image to my local system.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8A
```

actually *is* image - bytes encoded to string using base64, you might use [base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) built-in module to get it as file. Consider following simple example:

```
import base64
txt = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8A"
content = base64.b64decode(txt.split(',')[-1])
with open('image.png','wb') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

it will create `image.png` file in current working directory.

Comment: Tried it. But returns an empty png file, as @Georgiy mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This base64 data:
`iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8A` 
It is empty png image (it is not relevat image)

Usually this `base64 data` occure on e-commerce websites for products which don't have images.

I recommend You to interpret this products with `base64....` as products without image.

Comment: But on checking the product against the website, the images are present. Tried the link in src of img tag as well.